# MySQL: Displaying only the info in one table that is not already in displayed from another table

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to display all user's names and their availability for a specific match. The following code does that. Might not be the easiest way but I am new to this and it works for now.

```
//Display match dates and times(showing all matches)
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM matches 
                        WHERE tid=:tid /*AND datetime BETWEEN (NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 28 DAY)*/
                        ORDER BY datetime');
$stmt->bindParam(':tid', $tid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
      echo "
        <h2>".date("F j",strtotime($row["datetime"])). " @ ".date("g:i A",strtotime($row["datetime"]))."<br></h2>                               
        <h3>"$row[location] Match <br> vs $row[opponent]</h3>";
      echo "<table>             
        <tr>
          <th>Player</th>
          <th>Availability</th>
        </tr>
      </table>";


//Get available(Yes) users first and last names to display                                  
$stmtY = $conn->prepare("SELECT user.first, user.last
                         FROM user 
                         INNER JOIN match_part ON user.uid=match_part.uid
                        WHERE mid=:mid  AND availability = 'Yes'");
$stmtY->bindParam(':mid', $row['mid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmtY->execute();
    while ($rowY = $stmtY->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
      echo "<table class='match-avail'>             
        <tr>
          <td>$rowY[first] $rowY[last]</td>
          <td><span style='color: #70db62'>&#10004;</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
    }   

//Get unavailable(No) users first and last names to display 
$stmtN = $conn->prepare("SELECT user.first, user.last
                         FROM user 
                         INNER JOIN match_part ON user.uid=match_part.uid
                         WHERE mid=:mid  AND availability = 'No'");
$stmtN->bindParam(':mid', $row['mid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmtN->execute();
    while ($rowN = $stmtN->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
      echo "<table class='match-avail'>             
        <tr>
          <td class='Avail_No'>$rowN[first] $rowN[last]</td>
          <td><span style='color: #b20000'>&#10008;</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
    }
```

The above gives me the exact information I want.

Where I am stuck is...

I have team_members table (tmid, uid, tid) with a list of all players on a given team

A match_part table (mpid, mid, uid, availability) with the availability of the players who have entered their availability for a specific match.

I now want to show the people who have not yet given their availability. Therefore, I need to show the team_members names who do not exist in the match_part table. So I need to display only the names of players that are in the team_members table and not in the match_part table.

So something along the lines of...

```
$stmtU = $conn->prepare("SELECT user.first, user.last
                         FROM user
                         INNER JOIN team_members ON user.uid=team_members.uid
                         INNER JOIN match_part ON user.uid=match_part.uid
                         WHERE ***team_member.uid is not in match_part.uid***");
$stmtU->bindParam(':tid', $tid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmtN->bindParam(':mid', $row['mid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmtU->execute(); 
    while($rowU = $stmtU->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
        echo "<table class='match-avail'>           
          <tr>
            <td>$rowU[first] $rowU[last]</td>
            <td>?</td>
          </tr>
        </table>";
      }
```

Sorry for the lengthy post but I figured the information might help understanding the goal here. Thank you to all who have any thoughts/solutions. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correct you need  the team_members.uid that are  not in match part 
for this you could use a not in with subselect

```
  $stmtU = $conn->prepare("SELECT user.first, user.last
                           FROM user
                           INNER JOIN team_members ON user.uid=team_members.uid
                           where team_members.uid not in ( select uid from match_part)");
```

Comment: Awesome! That does it, just had to add WHERE to both parts and got exactly what I wanted. Thank you!